# Generic Authentication Filter in Spring Security used for Authentication

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security, servlet-filters

I'm new to Spring Security and would like to learn the authentication process a little bit better

Here's what I found on the Internet related to the topic if I'm wrong on the process please let me know:

1. The authentication process begins in the `Filter` that might be part of a `FilterChain`. The filter might be of type `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`. The HTTP request is intercepted and there's an attempt to create an `Authentication Request` (an object of a class that implements the `Authentication` interface, i.e. `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`).
2. The `Authentication` object gets delegated to the `AuthenticationManager`.
3. Based on what has been passed to the `AuthenticationManager` it delegates it to the appropriate `AuthenticationProvider` (i.e. `DaoAuthenticationProvider`) where the REAL authentication takes place.
4. The `AuthenticationProvider` sends the fully authenticated `Authentication` object to the `AuthenticationManager`.
5. In the `Filter` where the `AuthenticationManager` was invoked, `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authResult);` gets called and the authentication process is finished.

My question is all about concrete implementations of the `Filter` class and the `FilterChain` related to authentication.

In our application most authentication filters extend `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` and the FilterChain is of class `CompositeFilter`. What are the de-facto "right" implementations of this interfaces? I apologise in advance for such a silly question but still need to learn this concept.

Comment: Everything you described from your research is correct. Unfortunately, the question is not clear to me. Can you please clarify the question with more details? Note: Spring Security uses the `FilterChainProxy` and a list of `SecurityFilterChain`, not a `CompositeFilter`.

Comment: My main question is about most commonly used classes (implementations) of the interfaces `Filter` and `SecurityFilterChain` regarding the authentication process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SecurityFilterChain` has one implementation, `DefaultSecurityFilterChain`.

There are too many implementations of `Filter` for one implementation to be considered most common. The available authentication filters in Spring Security that extend `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` are `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`, `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter`, and `Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter`.

The "right" filter to use depends largely on your use case.